# How to set DB log only to log CRON TYPE and SEVERITY NOTICE message?

Tags: 8, log-messages

I want to log only CRON TYPE and SEVERITY NOTICE message in db log , want to exclude all other types like notice, alert, critical, info, debug etc.,
Is there any way to prevent this, or should i write any custom coding for this?
if custom coding for where i can prevent logging other types in DBLOG.

Answer (score 1):

The Drupal error handler [`_drupal_error_handler_real()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!errors.inc/function/_drupal_error_handler_real/8.2.x) utilized PHP's [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to determine what gets logged to the DB. By setting the PHP `error_reporting` to `E_ERROR` it will only PHP errors.

This PHP setting can be set in many places: the system **php.ini**, a **php.ini**/**.user.ini** instance in webroot, **.htaccess** in Apache. The Drupal centric way to do this, is to use [`ini_set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function in **settings.php**:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
```

See PHPs [error constant page](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) for other values to set `error_reporting`.

Comment: I want to log all these in DB log like CRON TYPE and SEVERITY NOTICE, not other messages. Updated Question can you kindly check this.